# How to find the place where font-size for input is set?

Tags: html, css

Have a page with a table in it. Some table's cells have `<input>` element inside.

Now font-size attribute of `<input>` elements is 13px. The aim - set font-size attribute for `<input>` to 12px.

First, I want to find where font-size attribute is set.
Using Chrome, Inspect Element context menu item for the `<input>` element, then moving to Styles tab I found:

- `<body>` element has 14px value for font-size, but this value is strikethrough.
- `<table>` element's class has 12px value for font-size, and this value is active (not strikethrough).
- there's no more information about font-size attribute of `<input>` element, it's classes or it's parents.
- **FireFox shows `input > -moz-use-system-font` value as Best Match.**

The question is: how to find the place, where 13px value is set for the `<input>` element, using Chrome or FireFox?

And the another question - can I apply some css style to `<table>` element with font-size attribute to apply it for every `<input>` element in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
table input {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Dear @flopet17, it works. But can you describe, why? Why simple table { font-size: 12px;} doesn't work?

Comment: Because you are referring to all the input elements inside the table element like here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp

Comment: Dear @flopet17, and why simple `table { font-size: 12px;}` doesn't work?

Comment: @omickron, `table { font-size: 12px;}` sets only the font size of the table. Each element, including each table cell and each `input` element, has its own font size.

Comment: Yes, @jukka-k-korpela, you're right. But when I use `table { font-size: 12px;}`, it applies the font-size for all table elements but the inputs. Why not for inputs?

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Developer Tools (inspect element or F12), in the Elements window you can click the second tab 'Computed' to see what style is applied to a certain element:

[image: Chrome Developer Tools Computed Tab]

It will tell you what style  is responsible for the font setting. In the example below, it is line 3313 in bootstrap.css.

You can also enable 'Show inherited properties'.

Now for your second question, Add the following to your stylesheet:

```
table input {
    font-size:13px;
}
```

(input elements inherit their font size from the browser stylesheet, or from any other style for a specific HTML tag)

Answer (score 0):

moz only works in firefox and webkit for chrome

If you want to give font size for every input then just give

```
input
    { 
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

If you just want to give font size for inputs with in table means then give

```
   table input {
             font-size: 13px;
        }
```

The same answer given by Flopet , the style is going from right to left first it will see for tables and then it sees inputs with in table and font size is applied thats all

Comment: Why `table input {...}` works, but `table {...}` doesn't? In my case the input is located inside the table.